# Run the cmd ''ipconfig/flushdns'' command each certain time using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, recently I start to learn and mess with Python and I want to make a code that could open the Windows 10 cmd and run the command "ipconfig/flushdns" automatically each certain time but I don't know exactly how to write it.

I have already tried doing something with the "subprocess" and "os" modules but I still do not get what I want.

```py
import os
os.system("ipconfig")
```

Comment: `os.system("ipconfig /flushdns")` works fine for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I want to make a code that could open the Windows 10 cmd and run the command "ipconfig/flushdns" automatically each certain time*

Do this:
make a py file and add this code:

```
import os
os.system('ipconfig/flushdns')
```

Save this file with any name but extension ***pyw*** 
Now add this file into your startup folder, or 
Make use of scheduler to make it run whenever you want.
I asked for extension ***pyw*** rather than py because ***pyw*** keeps shell hidden, which is cool Ain't it?

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly with the scheduler. Didn't know the `.pyw` extension thing, thanks for the input.